# Circle not refreshing properly with Canvas, fiddle provided

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using javascript canvas to animate some shapes. It currently has a refresh rate of 60 fps.

Animating the rectangles works well, here's how I draw them :

```
this.ctx.fillStyle = shape.colour;
this.ctx.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
```

This is how I create the circles :

```
this.ctx.fillStyle = shape.colour;
this.ctx.arc(shape.x,shape.y,shape.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
this.ctx.fill();
```

Basically, my shapes move from the top to the bottom of the screen, the rectangles move down fine, but the circles dont seem to refresh.

Below is an image showing this, the rectangle is half way down, the circle moves down but the 'old circles' dont get deleted :

[image: The white is the circle not refreshing, the red is the rectange moving down screen]

If need be, I'll try create a JSFiddle showing the exact problem, but maybe someone knows whats going on without it :)

Managed to get a fiddle together to show the exact problem : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/suuwe4wc/5/

Comment: Show how you update the properties of `shape`, and how you subsequently redraw

Comment: @SethBattin managed to get a fiddle to show the exact problem :) hope it helps

Comment: You need to define a new path for the arc. Add `ctx.beginPath()` befor the arc function.

Comment: @Blindman67 perfect. You can add an answer and ill accept ? Knew it was something so simple, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the fill or stroke functions directly for things like `ctx.fillRect` or `ctx.strokeText` the 2D renderer will create a new path for that. All other render functions that involve shapes will add to the current path.

If you are in a loop and you just have

```
ctx.arc(100,100,10,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.stroke();
```

each time your code loops you add to the current path. In most cases this ends up looking like you are leaving a trail.

To fix this you need to used `ctx.beginPath()` to start an new path.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100,100,10,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.stroke();
```

will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

working code: https://jsfiddle.net/suuwe4wc/7/

you need just add `ctx.beginPath();`:

`ctx.fillStyle = grd; //fill with gradient above
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.save();`